# No proposals in hot area of Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51

So I was browsing Area 51 when suddenly this came up:

[image: Area 51 bug]

I hit refresh, loaded it again, but there still was nothing.

The rest of the tabs work, but only hot is broken.

**EDIT:** It seems to be fixed.